# How can i end session when user was inactive

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi all i have seen several examples regarding the session. But i would like to know whether the following work as per my requirement or not. My requirement i will have some pages that user can access. If user visits a page and if he didn't perform any operations for 5 minutes or so i would like to redirect him to the default page available. This is what i have done

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms timeout="50"/>
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="5"  />
```

The script i wrote is as follows

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var maxInactiveInterval = 120;
function startCountdown() {
window.setTimeout(alertSessionTimeout, ((maxInactiveInterval - 60) * 1000));
 }
  function alertSessionTimeout() {
  alert("You're session is going to timeout in 1 minute.");
 }
</script>
```

and i call this script in my body as follows

```
body onload="startCountdown();">
```

I would like to know whether it works as per my requirement or not and also the best possible methods to aler user that the session is going to expire in few minutes when he was inactive

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you relay on the IIS where you can set the seesion time out or you can make change in you Web.Config file and set the session time out perio/ minutes. rather than writing script.

Something like:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

I hope you have seen this article for alerting user before session time out :  [Alert Session Time out in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AlertSessionTimeOut.aspx) the better way to achieve you want.

Comment: I think you haven't read the question carefully enough, the OP wants to know if his approach of warning the user that the session will expire is recommendable.

Comment: you missed the **alert user that the session is going to expire part**

Comment: I would like to impllement some thing like net banking application, when user is inactive for few minutes i would like say your session has been expired and redirect him to the page

Comment: But even when i am working on the form it is showing the alert as session going to expire

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Jquery idle time out plug in

http://philpalmieri.com/2009/09/jquery-session-auto-timeout-with-prompt/

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/